# Create a DIV dynamically based on DropDownList MVC (MVC3..)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, dynamic, html.dropdownlistfor

I am trying to create a DIV dynamically based on a dropdownlist.

The dropdown list:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-2">
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.AvailableProcesTypes, "Procestype *")
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ProcesTypeId, Model.AvailableProcesTypes, String.Empty, new { @id = "dropDownListId", @class = "form-control", required = "required" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProcesTypeId)
</div>
```

So I want to set the MVC Model.ProcesTypeId with the dropdown list and then render the DIV with the code below. However, ofcourse ProcesTypeId is null when I render the page and it gives an error.

```
foreach (var item in Model.ProcesTypes.Where(item => item.Id == Model.ProcesTypeId).Select(item => 
item.ProcesTypeWebappConfig).FirstOrDefault())
{
<div class="form-group col-md-2">
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DisplayNaam)
@Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.DisplayNaam, new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>
}
```

Hence, is there a way to make the code work? Or do I need to use jQuery for it? (I already tried that as well, but I can't make that work either, for example dynamically create a div)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

For now I created a dynamic div id with:

```
@foreach (var procesType in Model.ProcesTypes)
{
foreach (var webAppConfig in procesType.ProcesTypeWebappConfig)
{

string divId = "procesType" + procesType.Id + webAppConfig.Id;

<div class="form-group col-md-2" id="@divId">
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => webAppConfig.DisplayNaam)
@Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => webAppConfig.DisplayNaam, new { @class = "form-control" 
})
</div>
}
}
```

And some javascript which changes the divs based on the clicked item in the dropdown:

```
<script>
function hideOnLoad() {
    // Hide all divs where id contains 'procesType'
    $('div[id*="procesType"]').hide();
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    // Hide all divs on page load
    hideOnLoad();

    // Function which gets value on page load
    $('#dropDownListId').change(function () {
        var value = $(this).val();

        // First hide all divs, then show divs containing value
        if (value == '1') {
            hideOnLoad();
            $('div[id*="procesType1"]').show();
        } else if (value == '2') {
            hideOnLoad();
            $('div[id*="procesType2"]').show();
        } else {
            // If none is found, hide all
            hideOnLoad();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

This script can be updated and made more dynamic as well I think, but for now it is suffcient.